# Created a dyanmic class and function generator but method_body part doesnt work

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

```
class DynamicClass
  def initialize(class_name)
    @class_name = class_name
    Object.const_set class_name, Class.new
  end
  def def_method(method_name,method_body)
   Object.const_get(@class_name).send(:define_method, method_name, Proc.new{method_body} )
  end

  def call(method_name)
    puts "Hello, Your class #{@class_name} with method #{method_name} is ready. Calling: #{@class_name}.new.#{method_name}:"
    Object.const_get(@class_name).new.send(method_name)
  end
end

p 'Please enter the class name: '
class_name = gets.chomp
p 'Please enter the method name you wish to define: '
method_name = gets.chomp
p "Please enter the method's code: "
method_body = gets


n =DynamicClass.new(class_name)
n.def_method(method_name,method_body)
puts n.call(method_name)
```

Expected Output :

```
Please enter the class name: User
Please enter the method name you wish to define: greet
Please enter the method's code: "Welcome from #{self.class} class. I am #{self}"

Hello, Your class User with method greet is ready. Calling: User.new.greet:
"Welcome from User class. I am <User#123456>"
```

Actual Output

"Please enter the class name: " User

"Please enter the method name you wish to define: " greet

"Please enter the method's code: " Welcome from #{self.class} class. I am #{self}

Hello, Your class User with method greet is ready. Calling: User.new.greet:

Welcome from #{self.class} class. I am #{self}

method_body doesnt do string interpolation.., i think the error is using gets method any ideas ?..

Comment: In response to the prompt, `"Please enter the method's code: "`, if the user enters `"Welcome from #{self.class} class. I am #{self}\n"`, then `method_body #=> "Welcome from Object class. I am main\n"`, which is not what you want.

Comment: There are a few problems here (in addition to the one mentioned in my previous comment). 1. To create a class with methods you create an instance of `DynamicClass`. Why? That is, why is that preferable to simply having a method that constructs a class and another method that creates an instance method for the class given as an argument?...

Comment: ..2. You assign the dynamically-created class a name that is passed as an argument, and then invoke that method using the method name. Why bother with the method name? Once you have the anonymous class, say `klass` (an instance of `Class`), and have created instance methods for that class, isn't it easier to write `k = klass.new; k.public_send(meth, *args, &block)`, where `meth` (which holds a symbol you pass as an argument) is the name of one of `klass`' instance methods?

Comment: Since @Fernand has not shown that his answer provides the desired results you should check it  before awarding it the greenie. Have you done so? Regardless, most SO askers wait longer before selecting an answer, so as to not discourage other answers, to give those working on answers time to post and to give time for others to review answers that have been posted for correctness. Most askers wait a minimum of a couple of hours, some wait much longer, even a day or more, before making a selection. There's no rush!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there!
Just do the [evaluation](https://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/eval) to perform the string interpolation.

```
def def_method(method_name,method_body)
  Object.const_get(@class_name).send(:define_method, method_name, Proc.new{eval('"' + method_body + '"')} )
end
```

Comment: You could write `eval(method_body)` if the user has surrounded their reply with double quotes. For example, if `s = gets #=> "\"Cats have \#{n} lives\"\n"`, then `eval s #=> "Cats have 9 lives"`. Alternatively, the user could enter `%Q|Cats have \#{n} lives|`, in which case `s #=> "%Q|Cats have \#{n} lives|\n"` and `eval s #=> "Cats have 9 lives"`. What you have would work if single quotes could be used: `s = 'Cats have #{n} lives' #=> "Cats have \#{n} lives";  eval '"' + s + '"' #=> "Cats have 9 lives"`, but a single-quoted string cannot be entered with `gets`.